# How to write the quantity of lines in a file to a line in a seperate file using bash

Tags: bash, sed, pipe, wc

I want to count the number of lines in one file, and then overwrite a number in a second file with the number of lines. E.g.

`file1.txt`

```
Apples
Oranges
Bananas
```

`file2.txt`

```
num_lines_in_file_1 = 100
```

So I need to replace 100 with 3

`file2.txt`

```
num_lines_in_file_1 = 3
```

I seen that the `wc -l file1.txt` command can tell me the number of lines. And I know I can replace a line using `sed` e.g.

```
sed -i "s/num_lines_in_file_1 = 100/num_lines_in_file_1 = 3/" file2.txt
```

However I don't understand how you would pipe | the wc command into sed? Would it happen inside the regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use command substitution:

```
sed -i "s/num_lines_in_file_1 = 100/num_lines_in_file_1 = $(wc -l < file1.txt)/" file2.txt
```

You also don't need to repeat the whole phrase, sed can remember it for you:

```
sed -i "s/\(num_lines_in_file_1 = \)100/\1$(wc -l < file1.txt)/" file2.txt
```